# How do i Conditionally display a Screen/Widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement

```
//Part of the code

 login() {
    googleSignIn.signIn();
  }

  logout() {
    googleSignIn.signOut();
  }

  bool isAuth = false;


Scaffold buildUnauthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        //backgroundColor
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [
              Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
            ],
          ),
        ),
         GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  height: 70.0,
                  width: 260.0,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('images/example.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () => logout(),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
@override
Scaffold buildGuestLogin(context) {
    return Scaffold(
 
      body: Container(
        //backgroundColor
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [
              Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
            ],
          ),
        ),
         GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  height: 70.0,
                  width: 260.0,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('images/example.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () => login(),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        
      ),
    );
  }
```

THIS IS ONLY RETURNING THE FIRST PART. IF auth is false, it is not returning the Else condition

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return isAuth ? buildAuthScreen() : buildGuestLogin(context);
   
 }
```

Have tried swapping the conditions but still thesame

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isAuth ? buildGuestLogin(context) : buildAuthScreen();
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the bool value based on auth state, also ig it will be a future method, You can convert it to statefulWidget and

```dart
 login() async{
   final result = await googleSignIn.signIn(); /// you can return bool based on it
   setState(()=> isAuth = result));//depends 
  }

  logout() async{
   await googleSignIn.signOut();
   setState(()=> isAuth = false));
  }

  bool isAuth = false;
```